# Javascript not working for calculation

Tags: javascript, web-applications, if-statement, settings, var

Im creating a web app to help diabetics like myself. I am having trouble with a javascript that will automatically set my insulin to carb ratio {myFunction()}. It just wont show up. The code is...

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=2, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name= apple-mobile-web-app-capable content= yes />
    <meta name= apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style content= black />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11681462/untitled%20folder/Icon/Icon-SD-Iphone.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes= 114x114 href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11681462/untitled%20folder/Icon/Icon-HD-Iphone.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes= 72x72 href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11681462/untitled%20folder/Icon/Icon-SD-Ipad.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes= 144x144 href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11681462/untitled%20folder/Icon/Icon-HD-Ipad.png" />
    <Title> Diabetes Cal </Title>
    <script>
        function valuechanged() {
    var a = document.getElementById('textA').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('textB').value;
    var t = document.getElementById('textX').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('textY').value;
    var z = document.getElementById('textZ').value;
    var dec = t * 0.1;
    var x = parseFloat(dec).toFixed(1);
    if (+x - +y < 0) {
        var c = 0;
    }
         else
        {
            c = +x - +y;
        } 
       if (c < 0) {
        var l = 0;
       }
        else
        {
        var l = c / z;
        }
        var d = parseFloat(l).toFixed(2);
        if (a / b < 0)
        {
        var u = 0;
        }
        else
        {
        var u = a / b;
        }
        var e = parseFloat(u).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('labelS').innerHTML = e;
        document.getElementById('labelG').innerHTML = d;
        document.getElementById('labelX').innerHTML = +x;
        document.getElementById('labelA').innerHTML = a;
        document.getElementById('labelJ').innerHTML = +d + +e;
            }
        function myFunction(){  
    var TS=document.getElementById('textB')
     var date= new Date();
     var time = date.getHours();
    if (time<10)
         {
          CR = "8";
          }
        else if (time<16)
         {
          CR = "10";
          }
        else if (time<20)
         {
          CR = "5";
          }
        else
         {
         CR = "8";
          }
    TS.value= CR
    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body BGColor=orange onload="valuechanged();myFunction();" > <center><br> Bolus Wizard <br>
         <div>
            Bg (without Decimal)<br> 
        <input type="text" pattern=\d* id="textX" min="25" max="333" value="25" onchange="valuechanged();" /><br><label ID="labelX">-----</label> mmol/L<br>

        </div><hr width=45% color=black size=0.5>
        <div>
            Carbs<br> <input type="text" pattern=\d* ID="textA" max=300 value="0" onchange="valuechanged();" /><br>
        </div><hr width=45% color=black size=0.5>
        <div>
            Carb Ratio<br><input type="text" pattern=\d* ID="textB" value="" onchange="valuechanged();" /> 
        </div>
        <div>
            Target<br><input type="text" pattern=\d* ID="textY" value="6" onchange="valuechanged();" />
        </div>
    <div>
            Correction Factor<br><input type="text" pattern=\d* ID="textZ" value="2" onchange="valuechanged();" />
        </div>
    <div>
            Food<br>  <label ID="labelS">  ---</label> Units
        </div>
    <p>
    <div>
            Correction<br>  <label ID="labelG">  ---</label> Units
        </div>
    <p>
        <div>
            You Need...<br>  <label ID="labelJ">  ---</label> Units
        </div>
    <p>
    </center>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

I was hoping someone could debug my problem.t is confusing. The formula is 
`(Blood Sugar{x}-Target{y} -:- (Correction Factor{z})+ (carbs{a} -:- Carb ratio{b})` it was working before I added the decimal placement

`var dec = t * 0.1;
 var x = parseFloat(dec).toFixed(1);`

also if anyone could teach me how to create a settings for the

> TextZ, TextY and TextB

area on a different page that would be awesome. PM me(if you can on here)

Thanks SOO much

Comment: BTW, unary `+` is only required as a safeguard for addition, other mathetmatic operators will convert strings to numbers automatically (e.g. `c = +x - +y` can be `c = x - y`. You should test input values to ensure they convert to number appropriately before using them (this is independent of how you convert them to numbers).

Comment: if i do that it gives me NaN

Comment: It shouldn't (and doesn't for me), you must have mistyped something else.

Comment: That is possible. I'll change it, but it will still work with them on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the calculations are right but your code contains a line:

```
document.getElementById('labelA').innerHTML = a;
```

Problem is that your document doesn't contain an element with the id of labelA so getElementById returns `null` then you try to get `innerHTML` of null wich causes an Error.

If you comment out that line it seems to be doing something.

One tip: If you're using firefox, chrome or opera you can press F12 and check out the console for javascript errors. In your code you can use console.log to log from your code like:

```
console.log("is variable a what I think it is:",a);
```

Comment: +1 but strictly, *getElementById* returns `null` if it can't find the element.

Comment: @RobG you are correct, it does return null. I've updated the answer. And Brandon, good luck finishing the page. If you need any help please let us know.

Comment: Heaven forbid, a browser that follows the spec!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you need  to change this line:

```
  document.getElementById('labelA').innerHTML = a;
```

to this :

```
  document.getElementById('textA').innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: It helps greatly to add an explanation of why the error occurred and why your answer fixes it.

Comment: you are on the right path, but i didn't need `document.getElementById('labelA').innerHTML = a;` at all. its still there from the code I copied from.